# i am mapping over an object and making <tr> from it using info from it and making an html table render with react but there are some extra empty <tr>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Essentially, I used Object.entries() on an object and then .map() over it and a lot more complicated stuff

This is the code I used.

```
           {Object.entries(ratings).map((item) => {
            item.filter(n => n);
            return (item.map((Item) => {
              if (!Item.points === []) return (<></>);
              if (Item.points) {
                console.log(Item.points);
                return (
                  <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                    <td>{Item.points.at(-1)}</td>
                  </tr>
                )
              }
            }))
           }) ?? null}
```

and ratings looks like this

```
[
    {
      "name": "Bullet",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Blitz",
      "points": [
        [2023, 6, 4, 864],
        [2023, 6, 9, 1106],
        [2023, 6, 10, 1139],
        [2023, 6, 11, 1174]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Rapid",
      "points": [
        [2023, 6, 3, 1082],
        [2023, 6, 4, 1035],
        [2023, 6, 5, 1054],
        [2023, 6, 6, 1081],
        [2023, 6, 7, 1076],
        [2023,6,8,1157],
        [2023,6,9,1131],
        [2023,6,10,1145],
        [2023,6,11,1157]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Classical",
      "points": [
        [2023,6,9,1262]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Correspondence",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Chess960",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "King of the Hill",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Three-check",
      "points": [
        [2023,6,5,1628]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Antichess",
      "points": [
        [2023,6,5,1090]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Atomic",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Horde",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Racing Kings",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Crazyhouse",
      "points": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Puzzles",
      "points": [
        [2023,6,3,1353],
        [2023,6,4,1404],
        [2023,6,5,1306],
        [2023,6,8,1499],
        [2023,6,9,1514],
        [2023,6,10,1838],
        [2023,6,11,1766],
        [2023,6,12,1781]
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "UltraBullet",
      "points": []
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, it has some empty arrays like for "Bullet". React keeps creating a bunch empty  that I don't want. How can I remove them. This is my code, but at some point it got a little out of hand and I'm now confused.
ive also tried filtering with length but it says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

changed my code to this

```
           {Object.entries(ratings).map((item) => {
            return (Object.keys(item).filter(o => o.points?.length).map((Item) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                    <td>{Item.points.at(-1)}</td>
                  </tr>
                )
            }))
           }) ?? null}
```

and now i dont get any errors but no elements are being created

Comment: if ratings is an array then why are you using Object.entries function

Comment: note that in javascript the array methods map, filter, and reduce all return modified *copies* of the array, they dont modify the original array. So the line using the 'filter' method in your code is not actually doing / affecting anything. Also - evaluating " === []" will always yield false in javascript, since arrays are objects, and "[]" is instantiating a new array with a new reference each time its used. You can try typing "[] === []" in the console to illustrate this point. As an alternative, you can check if the array's length is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by changing the code to this

```
{Object.values(ratings).filter(o => o.points.length).map((item) => {
      return (
          <tr key={uuidv4()}>
             <td>{item.points.at(-1)}</td>
          </tr>
       )
}) ?? null}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` by the length of the `points` array of each object before `map`ping.

```js
return item.filter(o => o.points.length).map(Item => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: i get an error about .length being undefined when trying that

Comment: @HoodedHacker Is `ratings` actually an array or an object?

Comment: ratings is an object

Comment: i think its because ratings is actually a useState variable or smth and its being set by useEffect so its null / undefined at some point and so it doesnt have .length